# Multiple markers with specific infotemplate content

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

When I'm looping through a list of addresses, I'm able to plot the markers for all the addresses fine. But when I click on any marker, the infowindow content shows data of only the last marker. How do I solve this?

### Javscript

```
var map ={};
map.markers = [];
map.addresses = [
    {
        'line': '2101 K St',        
        'ref_no': '160621-000005'        
    },
    {
        'line': '2131 K St',        
        'ref_no': '170708-000015'        
    },
    {
        'line': '2321 K St',        
        'ref_no': '170707-000028'
    }
];

.
.
.
map.map_object = new Map("esri_map", {
   basemap: "topo",
   center: [<lat>, <lng>],
   zoom: 12
});

var locator = new Locator("http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");
for(var i = 0; i < map.addresses.length; i++)
{
    var addr = map.addresses[i];
    var params = {
        countryCode: "US",
        maxLocations: 1,
        address: {"SingleLine": addr.line}
    };
    locator.addressToLocations(params, function(candidates){
        locatorDone(candidates, addr);
    });
}

function locatorDone(candidates, addr)
{
    .
    .
    .
    var html = "<h5>"+addr.line+"</h5>";            
    html += "<p>Ref#: "+addr.ref_no+"</p>";
    var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate(addr.ref_no, html); // <--- Problem lies here
    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(pt, symbol,'',infoTemplate);
    map.map_object.graphics.add(graphic);
    map.markers.push(graphic);
}
```

> P.S: I've solved similar problems (in case of Google Maps API) by using ***closures***. But I'm not sure how to use that in this case.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Can you provide us with a fiddle and some dummy data to replicate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the inside of the `for` loop in a self invoking function which will provide the *closure*. Something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < map.addresses.length; i++) 
    (function (i) {
        var addr = map.addresses[i];
        var params = {
            countryCode: "US",
            maxLocations: 1,
            address: {"SingleLine": addr.line}
        };
        locator.addressToLocations(params, function(candidates){
            locatorDone(candidates, addr);
        });
    })(i)
```

This will make `i` local to this code block. As it is now in your code all `addr` are referencing the last address because the `for` loop has finished running when you call `locatorDone` asynchronously. Alternatively you can use `let` like so: `for (let i = 0; ...` if you don't need this code to run on Internet Explorer below version 11.

Comment: wouldn't `addresses.forEach(function(address){ })` work as well, since it creates a new scope due to a function call _and_ be better readable.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Out of 5 addresses, the infowindow is showing data of 4th address if I follow this method.

Comment: @Marco it will work on newer browsers. According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach) it will work only in IE 11. According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#compat-desktop) it will work on IE9. I trust mdn more so if IE8 is not a target then it is possible to use `forEach`.

Comment: You could just use the polyfill or a shim library to account for that. But in any case, self executing function should work as well, I was just concerned about readability.

Comment: @asprin that's strange. But it's really hard to guess what's going on without the actual code. Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeh, on it (jsfiddle)

Comment: Very strange. It's working in fiddle. So I copy pasted the code from there and voila! It starts to work in my application too. Perhaps cache issue.